# Autogrowing list with generics

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a domain model that features a number of 'elements', pieces of text that can be rendered to show rich content. There are pieces of HTML text, textile text, Flash objects and so on. The basic features of these elements are encapsulated in `AbstractElement`, which has implementations `HTMLElement`, `FlashElement` and so on. The model therefore has a `List<AbstractElement>` to contain all the elements it can have.

When editing the model, I want the user to be able to dynamically add elements, and save these when the user submits the form. So what I have is a form that is dynamically expandible with some JavaScript, which results in the following form:

```
<form action=...>
    <!-- Other attributes -->
    <textarea name="object.elements[0].content"/>
    <textarea name="object.elements[1].content"/>
    <!-- Some elements are based on text, others on files -->
    <input type="hidden" name="object.elements[2].file" value="somevalue"/> 
    <textarea name="object.elements[3].content"/>
    <!-- Submit button -->
</form>
```

This goes wrong when submitting the form. It's quite obvious why - when submitted, Spring tries to instantiate the required elements in the list. Since the list of elements contains objects of type `AbstractElement` which is abstract, Spring cannot instantiate new elements.

How would I go about having Spring instantiate the proper type of element? Could add type information in the form, and have some ModelAttribute do it? How would that work? Is there something I can do in the model that'll do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by implementing a ModelAttribute that constructs the list of elements by parsing the raw form data. Parsing the raw form data can be used by using the `HttpServletRequest` object, looping through the parameter map and just create the required objects 'by hand'. It's reusable if you put it in a helper function, though I need a ModelAttribute in every controller I use it in.

It's not the ideal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to create one (or more ) customer property editors which can take the request parameters and convert them to the correct class instances to add to the collection.

Spring uses PropertyEditor instances registered with the data binder to bind request parameters.  In cases where the default set of PropertyEditors can't determine the correct type, you can register your own editors to handle the logic.

The process is described in the Spring docs at this link:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Specifically, see section 5.4.2.1 on how to register customer property editors.

You can register your property editors using the registerCustomEditor() method of the WebDataBinder class in the initBinder() method of your controller (identified with the @InitBinder annotation).

Comment: Isn't a PropertyEditor designed to process a single text value (like a date format) to a Java Object? How would I add additional request parameters to it?

Comment: From your question, it seemed like the end user was populating various textareas on an HTML form and submitting it.  On submission, I thought you wanted to somehow determine the correct type of object to instantiate based on the contents of each textarea.  You can use a PropertyEditor to convert between a string and any type of object so I thought that would work for you.  If I'm not understanding the form correctly, please provide more detail and I'll try to help.

Comment: As you can see in the example form it isn't certain up front that the element will have a 'content' attribute. It could have a 'file' attribute instead. A PropertyEditor couldn't listen to that. Furthermore, different types of text based content cannot neccessarily be differentiated based on the contents of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try instantiating the formObject yourself by creating a ModelAttribute method which would return concrete object.
e.g.

```
@ModelAttribute("bindingObj")
public AbstractObject initElementList() {
    AbstractObject obj = new ConcreteObject();
    obj.setElements(new ArrayList<ConcreteElement>);
    return obj;
}

@RequestMapping(...)
public ModelAndView requestHandler(@ModelAttribute("bindingObj") AbstractObject) {
   ....
}
```

Spring would first invoke the initElementList and add the result to the internal modelMap. And then invoke requestHandler with this value.

The downside of this approach is that you would still end up having a reference to the concrete class. But if you have sub-classes deriving from your base controller, then it may help.

Comment: Although I didn't mention it in the question, it would be beneficial for the solution to be easily reusable across controllers - there are more models that have a list of elements. It seems to me that this is very specific for one controller?

Comment: Custom PropertyEditor is an option, but I am not sure how you will be able to resolve the concrete type for the list element in the editor. Because each controller knows what list element it needs to bind to, perhaps controller is the best place for this.